# Saturated sound when playing PCM16 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, pcm

I am trying to play raw PCM16 buffers with the `AudioContext` object. The sound does indeed play, but in a very saturated way.

The problem may come from converting unsigned 16bit integers to [-1.0 ; 1.0] floats, but I do not see any problem with what I am doing.

I made a minimal html sample below to ease reproduction. The `output.raw` file can be obtained from an MP3 file with the following command:

```
MP3FILE=myfile.mp3
ffmpeg -i $MP3FILE -f s16le -ac 1 -acodec pcm_s16le output.raw
```

I use Linux Chromium `Version 38.0.2125.111 (290379) (64-bit)`.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: directly loading PCM32 (s32le) samples exhibits the same problem.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "output.raw", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var context = new window.AudioContext();

  var pcm16Buffer = new Uint16Array(oReq.response);
  var frameCount = pcm16Buffer.length;
  var channels = 1;
  var buffer = context.createBuffer(channels, frameCount, context.sampleRate);

  for (var channel = 0; channel < channels; ++channel) {
    var channelBuffer = buffer.getChannelData(channel);
    for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) {
      channelBuffer[i] = pcm16Buffer[i] * 2 / 65535 - 1;
    }
  }

  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start();
};

function run() {
  oReq.send();
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:run()">run</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**ANSWER:**
The above for loop converting PCM16 to PCM32 is incorrect as it does not properly convert two's complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having ffmpeg output signed 16 bit data, but then you are reading it in JavaScript through the `Uint16Array` typed array, which is unsigned 16 bit. This is not going to give you the -32k to +32k values in the file shifted to 0 to 64k; values are stored in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) so negative values will appear as large positive values. Primarily what you need to do is change `pcm16Buffer` to an `Int16Array`.

Your conversion to floating point can then be a straightforward

```
channelBuffer[i] = pcm16Buffer[i] / 32768;
```

Comment: If a value is positive divide on 32767, negative 32768,ie. `... =  pcm16Buffer[i] < 0 ?  pcm16Buffer[i] / 32768 :  pcm16Buffer[i] / 32767;`

Answer (score 0):

Web Audio API can only render PCM buffers, so no matter where the audio originates the process must ultimately supply that format.  First, verify your input file plays OK using a different tool like Audacity.  The following is given an input WAV file from which it extracts the raw PCM buffer prior to rendering.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

        var audio_context, gain_node, source_node;
        var chosen_audio_file_url = "output_2.wav";

        // log if an error occurs
        function on_error(e) {

            console.log("ERROR - " + e);
        }

        try {

            window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext ||
            window.webkitAudioContext ||
            window.mozAudioContext ||
            window.oAudioContext ||
            window.msAudioContext;

            audio_context = new AudioContext();
            console.log("cool audio context established");

        } catch (e) {

            alert("Web Audio API is not supported by this browser");
        }


        gain_node = audio_context.createGain(); // Declare gain node
        gain_node.connect(audio_context.destination); // Connect gain node to speakers

        source_node = audio_context.createBufferSource();
        source_node.connect(gain_node);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', chosen_audio_file_url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        // When loaded decode the data
        request.onload = function() {

            // decode the data
            audio_context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {

                console.log(chosen_audio_file_url, ' ... buffer.length ', buffer.length);

                source_node.buffer = buffer;
                source_node.start(0);

                // ---

            }, on_error);
        }

        function run() {
            request.send();
        }

    </script>

    <a href="javascript:run()">run</a>
</body>

</html>
```

let us know if you need something more

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My files are perfectly correct, as I am able to go back to WAV using "ffmpeg -y  -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 1 -i output.raw file.wav". 

Your code sample does work, but unfortunately I cannot use `decodeAudioData()`. Have you ever tried directly forging buffers the way I do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to convert from unsigned to signed but your code isn't doing anything that could change a sign.  First, shift your unsigned 16 bit (0-65536) to signed (-32767 to 32767) by subtracting 32767. Then divide by 32767 to scale to -1.0 to 1.0. Also, make sure your division is a floating point division.

```
channelBuffer[i] = (pcm16Buffer[i]-32767) / 32767.0;
```

Comment: I think your equation is just another writing of mine.

Comment: I don't know the details of java script but it sure looks like yours is doing integer arithmetic.